# Retaining app package ID when updating from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 store app

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, windows-8.1

I have an App that is currently published to the Windows Store, as a Windows 8.1 App. (Published in 2013)

I have since created a new UWP app for the Windows 10 store that will replace it. It has a different identity, so it does not load the same save data.

What and how do I make my UWP 10 app use the Windows 8 identity?

(The new app is completely compatible with older save data and provides a superior experience)

Comment: This will be pushed as an update to Windows 10 machines.

Comment: You could try Project > Store > Associate with the Store, associate it with your w8.1 app and maybe it'll get the same identity...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What and how do I make my UWP 10 app use the Windows 8 identity?

First, update your submission as usual, associate your UWP project (like @Marian Dolinsky's comment) with the 8.1 app name and then the identity info will be automatically synced. Just [package your UWP project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps) and upload the .appxupload file as your package. After uploading it, your app will have two packages.

Additionally, you don't need to delete your 8.1 package. To prevent previous customer from getting your UWP package, please make sure that you update the `TargetDeviceFamily` element in your appx manifest to include only the particular device family that you wish to support.

```
TargetDeviceFamily Name          = An alphanumeric string. May contain period and dash characters.
                MinVersion       = A version string in quad notation, "Major.Minor.Build.Revision".
                MaxVersionTested = A version string in quad notation, "Major.Minor.Build.Revision". />
```

Because the Device families selection in **Pricing and availability** in Dashboard only applies to your new acquisition. The customer who had your app on earlier OS (Windows Phone 8) will be updated to your UWP package once they upgrade to Windows 10.

For more details, please refer to [Guidance for app package management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/guidance-for-app-package-management?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).